# Local path connected and connected implies path connected

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I am very close to proving that if a metric space $X$ is locally path-connected and connected, then it is path connected. I am stuck on the last step.

> Let $X$ be connected and locally path connected. Let $x \in X$, and define $A$ to be the set of points path connected to $x$. $x$ is connected to itself, so $A$ is nonempty. Because $X$ is connected, if $A$ is open and closed, it must equal $X$ (since it is not $\emptyset$). We show that $A$ is open. Let $a \in A$. By local path connectedness, there exists an open ball $U \ni a$ that is path connected. Let $u \in U$, so $u$ is path connected to $a$. But $a$ is path connected to $x$, so $u$ is path connected to $a$. So $u \in A$, so $U \subset A$, so we've found an open ball around $a$ that's contained in $A$, so $A$ is open.

My difficulty is in showing $A$ is closed. It's enough to show that $A = \overline{A}$.

> To show $A$ is closed, we prove $A = \overline{A}$. Clearly $A \subset \overline{A}$. For the reverse inclusion, let $y \in \overline{A}$. As $\overline{A} \subset X$ and $X$ is path-connected, there exists a open ball $U \ni y$ that is path=connected. **Then $U \cap A$ is nonempty.** Let $t \in U \cap A$. Since $t \in A$, $t$ is path-connected to $x$. Since $t \in U$ and $y \in U$, $t$ is path-connected to $y$. Therefore, $y$ is path-connected to $x$, so $y \in A$. So $\overline{A} \subset A$, so $A = \overline{A}$.

I think every step of this proof is fine, but to talk about such a $t$, I have to argue that $U \cap A$ is nonempty, but I can't think of an argument for this.

Comment: In the second paragraph, when you say "there exists an open ball $U \ni v$", do you mean "there exists an open ball $U \ni y$"?

Comment: Yes, this is a typo. Thanks.

Comment: Well, $y\in \bar A $, so every open neighbourhood of $y $ intersects $A $.

Comment: It is easier to argue by contradiction to show that the complement of $A$ is also open.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $U \cap A \neq \emptyset$ follows immediately from the fact that $U$ is a neighbourhood of $y \in \overline{A}$. One of the many equivalent conditions for membership in the closure of $A$ is that every neighbourhood of the given point intersects $A$.

If you prefer it done sequentially, we know that $y \in \overline{A}$ if and only if there exists a sequence $a_n \to y$, meaning that, for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some $N$ such that
$$n \ge N \implies d(a_n, y) < \varepsilon.$$
Taking $\varepsilon$ to be the radius of the open ball $U$, we get
$$n \ge N \implies a_n \in U \cap A.$$
Thus, $U \cap A \neq \emptyset$.